# Redirecting out of a directory

Tags: php, html

I have a CMS, and I'm developing a mobile site outside the CMS folders. I have included the CMS file to use all of the functions from the CMS.

```
<?php include_once'/home/flyeurov/public_html/core/codon.config.php';?>
```

On the mobile site, I have a login form. The information submits back to the CMS using the functions from the included file.

```
<form name="loginform" action="<?php echo url('/login');?>" method="post">
```

On submit, this will take it to site_url/index.php/login. Just above the Submit button for the form, I've hidden a redirect input but I want to be able to go back in terms of directories, in order to find /mobile directory.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redir" value="../mobile/crew_center.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
<input class="login-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" />
```

This should redirect it to m.site_url/crew_center.php ('m' is the path for /mobile directory) but it's instead redirecting it like this, and refuses to go back:

```
site_url/index.php/mobile/crew_center.php
```

How can I get it to redirect properly? I'm hoping I haven't confused anyone.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to redirect to `../mobile/crew_center.php` _after_ the form submission was processed?

Comment: Correct. It redirects to `index.php/profile` on the CMS however I'd like to display a different page for the user on a mobile site.

Comment: So in the PHP script where you process the login form, you are doing a redirect like this: `header('Location: $_POST['redir']);` or something similar, right?

Comment: This is how the login file looks: http://pastebin.com/ZbhYYY9n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CMS file, replace this:

```
$this->post->redir = str_replace('index.php/', '', $this->post->redir);
header('Location: '.url('/'.$this->post->redir));
```

With this:

```
if (isset($_POST['mobileVersion'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/crew_center.php');
} else {
    $this->post->redir = str_replace('index.php/', '', $this->post->redir);
    header('Location: '.url('/'.$this->post->redir));
}
```

And in the HTML of the login form add another [hidden input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.hidden.html):

```
<input type="hidden" name="mobileVersion" value="True">
```

That's the only way to do this that I can think of.

Comment: I need this actually for the CMS to work, is there anyway to combine them both? Perhaps use `Location: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and fill the rest using form action?

Comment: Yes, there's an even better way now that I think about it. In the HTML of your login form, replace the `<input type="hidden" name="redir" value="../mobile/crew_center.php" />` with `<input type="hidden" name="redir" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/mobile/crew_center.php" />`. You'll have to find out where is the mobile directory though.

Comment: It does this instead `site_url/index.php//home/flyeurov/public_html/mobile/mobile/crew_center.php`

Comment: The link after you login is now as follows: `site_url/home/flyeurov/public_html/mobile/crew_center.php`. A 404 Page Not Found is displayed. The path seems to be right. Would it just need `site_url/mobile/crew_center.php` then?